# VBA ADODB Connection close taking too long - Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, ms-access-2013

I'm the using ADODB connection to obtain data from an Access 2013 database and display it in Excel. I have successfully developed an efficient project (time wise) in VBA using Excel 2013.

However, when I tried to execute my excel application in Excel 2010, there was clearly a decrease in performance in some actions.

I managed to find that the cause for this lack of performance in Excel 2010 was the time Excel 2010 takes to release database connections from memory.

Below, I provide two examples of code that run slow in Excel 2010 but not in Excel 2013.

I'm setting the variables to Nothing, just to confirm that is the release of these variables that is taking too long. If I don't set them to Nothing, the problem still persists, as when those variables go out of scope they get automatically released (the End Sub takes too long).

```
Sub test1()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String


    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Category"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.accdb"

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing ' Takes too long in Excel 2010, but runs instantinaly in Excel 2013.

End Sub
```

I've even tried to change my code to first start a Connection:

```
Sub test2()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSQL As String


    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.accdb"

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Category"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSQL, conn

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    conn.Close ' Takes too long in Excel 2010, but runs instantinaly in Excel 2013.

    Set conn = Nothing     
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

I was able to find that, in fact, is the closing of the connection that takes too long.

Example:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection


    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.accdb"

    conn.Close ' Takes too long in Excel 2010, but runs instantinaly in Excel 2013.
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE 2:

I've found that if I remain the connection open for at least 15 seconds or so, closing the connection will take no time..

So I've just changed my project to always have an opened connection to the database. Only when quiting Excel, the connection is closed.